# Windows 8 dual monitor controlling switch on/off/standby

Tags: windows, controls, monitor

I have two monitors connected via hdmi to a PC on Windows 8 and I need to control separately each of them by switching on/off and standby. I've found good source [code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11099/Turn-on-off-monitor) for the task, but only for 1 monitor.

And this code turn off both displays at time.

I suppose that HWND_BROADCAST parameter controls target display.

Any suggestions?